# Access a variable on QML and Javascript inside a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables, qml

I've been trying to find a solution for this for days but I simply can't manage how to do it.

I am trying to create a simple QML/Javascript code to access a JSON file and read it.

For this I need to get the JSON, write the values into a variable and then access them on my QML files (I have two, but they will be used for different purposes).

What I am doing is this :

```
function load(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", comicUrl, true)
    xhr.send()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                example = {
                    "url"   : jsonObject.url,
                    "alt"   : jsonObject.alt,
                    "img"   : jsonObject.img,
                }

                console.log("1")
            }
        }
    }
}

function doTheStuff2(value)
{
    console.log("3")
    console.log(example.url)
    console.log(example.alt)
    console.log(example.img)
}
```

If I do like this it will work because on my QML page I have this :

```
import "../src/jsonParser.js" as JSONParser

...

property var example: {
    "url": "",
    "alt": "",
    "img": ""
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    JSONParser.load("http://example.com/myfile.json");
    console.log("2")
    JSONParser.doTheStuff2(example.alt);
}
```

What I get is :

```
[D] onCompleted:109 - 2
[D] doTheStuff2:69 - 3
[D] doTheStuff2:73 - 
[D] doTheStuff2:74 - 
[D] doTheStuff2:75 -
[D] :42 - 1
```

The problem is that, after that I simply can't access the example variable in Javascript if a call another function (imagine that I need to acces those values to read them or simply to create a list).

If I do the inverse (use a JavaScript variable), the same appens but in reverse : I can use that value in Javascript but not in QML.

What I need is this :
A variable which can contain those informations I need (url, alt, img) stored at any time to be accesses. In this way if I want to reuse code of the load(url) in order to, in a for, repeat until I have all the others url alts and images, I simply could do that using that variable by writing in it and then writting on the listmodel with a .Set.

So How can I do this ?

Comment: Downvoted for the lack of code. You should provide the code that "can't access" to let us check it out. It seems to me you are pretty free to play around; [see this example for instance](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=spETQJYE).

Comment: I did show you all the code necessary, I can't access the example variable inside the javascript by any means. If I create a function with a simple console.log(example.img) it returns me undefined when on QML if I do console.log(example.img) it returns the img url.

The same happens in a reverse situation, if I create a example variable on javascript and acces and write it on javascript I can, but on QML if I write it I can't acces it because I get a undefined variable.

Comment: I've edited the example I've provided in the first comment...is it the issue you are facing? It works perfectly for me. by the way..it's not all the code! You could have provided the one you are talking about, instead of writing it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks to you I've found my mistake. My code was exactly like yours, but there was a two huge differences :
1 - I use Component.onCompleted to get the content with the XMLHttpRequest
2 - Also with Component.onCompleted I was calling the function to retrieve the values.

What I didn't understand was that the second function was launched when the first one didn't had any value yet. This is why it wasn't working. With this in mind how can I launch those two separate functions in the Component.onCompleted ? Is there any onVariableChanged or similar ?

Comment: This is something I don't understand... Shouldn't the code only exit the function when everything is done ? It doesn't make sense to me that it starts doing a second function while the first one is still running :S I mean the only solution I see is by using the onTextChanged (since it is the place where the variables result will be), but even that aproach isn't perfect.

Comment: It's not that strange. The `load` is executed asynchronously, resulting in the wrong behaviour you see. You can check the change of ANY variable via the `changed` handler, i.e. you can use `onExampleChanged` handler. However if you subsequently change the `example` property the handler is called again, and again and again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72099/discussion-between-bacarozzo-and-aliasbody).